# ESP32-C3 CAN bus GPIO pin choice seems critical?

Tags: esp32

I'm using ESP32-C3 to build a CAN application. I chose GPIO 19 for CAN_TX and GPIO 18 for CAN_RX. I found that my application doesn't work, so I decided to try something known and simple by running the `examples/peripherals/twai/twai_self_test` program on a commercial ESP32-C3 board with its default pins - GPIO 3 and GPIO 2 - just shorted together. This worked fine.

But when I changed (using `idf.py menuconfig`) to using GPIOs 19 and 18 as my application requires and shorting *those* pins together I cannot get the example program to run. It always fails at `twai_transmit()` with `ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE`.

Is there some restriction on which pins can support TWAI? What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Have you tried GPIO 4 and 5 ?

Comment: I never did. I stuck with pins 2 and 3. But I really don't want to waste those two pins in the "hold steady during reset" range of GPIOs on TWAI, so I may have to revisit this.